# matplotlib: How to eliminate wasted space from plot without changing aspect

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to display a plot with equal aspect in matplotlib.  Then I would like to truncate the y-portion of the plot for a closer view at the data.  However, the x-axis limits I am hoping to change automatically to fit the remaining visible portion of the data.

Here is my code thus far (using fake data for illustration purposes):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.plot([-2,-1,0,1,2], [4,1,0,1,4])
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
fig.show()
```

and the resulting image:

[image]

My question is, *How can I remove the whitespace from the left and right sides of the plot while preserving the aspect ratio, so the plot will be larger and fit the data better?*  Unfortunately, I may not know the exact x limits that I want or a formula to derive them given the y limits.

**edit:**  I would like the resulting image to look something like this:
[image]

Comment: Try `plt.tight_layout()` before the `show()`

Comment: I tried.  It didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I don't understand the desired outcome. Would you be able to fake an image of how it should look like?

Comment: store the values for the limits desired in a variable. i..e, if you want to preserve that aspect ratio, you would figure out what the ratio is that you want and set the limits accordingly.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misread, it's not the white space outside the axes you're trying to get rid of. Nevermind... I've not messed with equal aspect ratio so not sure what to try. I guess `ax.set_xlim()` doesn't do it for you?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest see my edit.

Comment: @kwinkunks I would have to know the x limits that I want.  I could work this out mathematically but I thought I would save some time and effort if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround is to mask both `x` and `y` based on the condition on `y` first and then plot

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-2,-1,0,1,2])
y = np.array([4,1,0,1,4])

cond = np.logical_and(y>=0, y<=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)

ax.plot(x[np.where(cond)], y[np.where(cond)])
ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does not appear to produce a plot with equal scales for x and y. Do you need to add `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')` before showing the figure?

Comment: Yes, for equal scale on both axes

Comment: Okay, well that's what the question asked for... adding it would improve your answer, IMO.

Answer (score 4):

What you're asking for is some kind of autoscaling based in the visible data. This is not implemented in matplotlib. You can do it manually though, i.e. based in the desired y limits, check which points would be visible and then set the x limits accordingly.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
line, = ax.plot([-2,-1,0,1,2], [4,1,0,1,4])

ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

ymin = 0
ymax = 1
ax.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
x,y = line.get_data()
cond = (y >= ymin) & (y <= ymax)
ax.set_xlim(x[cond].min(), x[cond].max())

plt.show()
```

[image]